# Как поменять надпись на кнопке через 4 секунды?

Tags: reactjs

Сейчас по клику на кнопку появляется и по второму клику исчезает картинка, а как через setTimeout сделать чтобы по клику на кнопку картинка исчезала через 4 секунды и на кнопке менялась надпись на Привет

```js
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react'
const Button = () => {
  // useEffect(() => {
  //   const time=setTimeout(()=>{
      
  //   },4000)
  //   return () => {
  //   }
  // }, [])
  const[click,setClick]=useState(true)
  return (
    <>
    <button onClick={()=>setClick(!click)}>Click me</button>
    {click? <img src='https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2019-05/1556945414_2.jpg'/> :null}
  </>
  )
}
export default Button
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Уточню по клику на кнопку Click me появляется картинка, через 4 секунды картинка исчезает, появляется кнопка с надписью Привет, картинка типа спиннера

Comment: Интересно как очистить  задержу если компонент будет размонтирован до того как отработает коллбэк в таймауте

Comment: `Интересно как очистить задержу если компонент будет размонтирован до того как отработает коллбэк в таймауте` - сделать `clearTimer(time)` в функции размонитрования.